# Empty content returned for a javascript bundle by cassette asset manager

Tags: javascript, string, cassette

I had an issue 3 times in the last few weeks with cassette since upgrading to v1.2.0 from v1.1.0. I've now rolled back to v1.1.0 and haven't seen the problem since.

I have a website in c# using .NET 4.0 running on IIS7 which has multiple javascript bundles managed by Cassette. Our Cassette configuration is:

```
public void Configure(BundleCollection bundles, CassetteSettings settings) {
    //bundle stylesheets
    bundles.AddPerSubDirectory<StylesheetBundle>("Content/Stylesheets");

    // Per-page JS (eventually may want separate folders as well)
    bundles.AddPerSubDirectory<ScriptBundle>("Content/Scripts/Pages");

    // Bundle all scripts except special cases above
    bundles.AddPerSubDirectory<ScriptBundle>("Content/Scripts",
    new ExcludeDirectorySearch("*.js", new[] {"Pages"}),
     b => b.Processor = new ScriptPipeline {
         Minifier = new MicrosoftJavaScriptMinifier(new CodeSettings { KillSwitch = 0x40000000000 })
     });
}
```

After running fine for a couple of days suddenly one of the javascript file bundles starts returning an empty javascript file, which causes my website to break. I've seen it happen against several different bundles, so it's not one particular bundle that fails.

I've put startup tracing on cassette and haven't seen anything show up there, apart from a few images missing in my css.

Each page of the website has at least 2 js bundles it refers to. One bundle is specific for the page and then there's a few generic bundles for jquery etc.

Rebuilding the bundles seemed to fix it once, although the other times I didn't notice it fixed until I restarted the application pool in IIS.

Does anybody have any idea what could cause this?

Thanks.

Comment: We've been experiencing this problem, it's a real pain.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this with a css bundle suddenly being empty. Had to restart the site to get it back again. Might have to leave debug=true on my site and can the bundling if this keeps happening.